# How to find and replace an IP address in many archives in linux

Tags: linux, find

Example:

```
find /tmp/example -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/10.20.1.110/10.10.1.40/g'
```

I need replace 10.20.1.110 to 10.10.1.40 in all archives inside /tmp/example.
But this command does not replace inside archives.

Comment: What kinds of archive are there?

Comment: *.xml, *.txt , *.py .*.jy . This archives types.

Answer (score 0):

> *.xml, *.txt , *.py .*.jy . This archives types.

These are not archives, but ordinary text file extensions; thus, if the `sed` command doesn't work for you, there must be another reason. It may be that the command is executed with insufficient priviledges - `sed -i` exits as soon as it cannot `rename` its temporary output file to the input file (as it's the case if the containing directory has the sticky bit `t` set and you don't own the file or the directory). Pay heed to error messages.

Comment: I look for treatment for the point scape.
Example: find / tmp / example -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's / 10 \ ./ 20 \ ./ 1 \ ./ 110 \ / 10.10.1.40/g'

Comment: @ua4 fv4r askljklb - If you're looking for something other than stated in your question, you should complete your question and add example input lines.